# $E[X^2] = \sum_{x=0}^{\infty}(2x+1)P[X>x]$

Tags: expected-value

How to prove $E[X^2] = \Sigma_{x=0}^{\infty}(2x+1)P[X>x]$? It is easy to use generating function to prove: $E[X]=\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}P[X>x]$. Given that $X$ is discrete random variable and with countable elements.

Comment: Your statement is wrong if $X$ is not a discrete r.v.

Comment: Thanks for your comment and sorry for the ambiguity. And I have adjusted my statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also, $X$ need to be positive.

**Hint**

Briefly, \begin{align*}
\mathbb E[X^2]&=\int_\Omega X^2\,\mathrm d \mathbb P\\
&=\int_\Omega \int_0^X2x\,\mathrm d x\,\mathrm d \mathbb P\\&=\int_\Omega \int_0^\infty 2x\boldsymbol 1_{\{X>x\}}\,\mathrm d x\,\mathrm d \mathbb P\\
&\underset{\text{Fubini}}{=}\int_0^\infty 2x\mathbb P\{X>x\}\,\mathrm d x.
\end{align*}
Using this previous formula yields :
$$\mathbb E [X^2]=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \mathbb P\{X>k\}\int_k^{k+1}2x\,\mathrm d x=...$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! That is a really nice derivation.